# Beanstalk-Docker configuration issues for serving HTTP/HTTPS requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, nginx, docker, ssl-certificate, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an application deployed on Elastic Beanstalk which is build using Ruby on Rails, Nginx-Passenger, Multi-container docker configuration. Load-balancer is also configured for the same.

I have also uploaded an SSL certficate(from third-party) to IAM. If I configure ContainerPort as 80 in Dockerrun.aws.json, then the application responds only over http, if Containerport configured as 443, then it responds only over https. Even if both ContainerPorts are specified in Dockerrun.aws.json, then Beanstalk uses only one out of them.

With beanstalk, I am not able to expose more than one port for my container. That is, I can either open it for http or https. Both does not work together. What I'm trying to achieve is if anyone visits the link on http, it should automatically re-direct to https and serve the request. Currently, at a time , only one of both will work due to Dockerrun.aws.json configuration.

I have also configured Load balancer configuration to use HTTPS. Screenshot below for your reference. Please let me know if I'm missing any configuration.

[Load_balancer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ds0K.png)